# User database using python & mySQL (storing hash and salt values for password)

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, mysql-workbench

I'm looking to create a database that stores a user's details from a 'register page'.
Currently I have the basic table in MySQL which stores the basic info (user id, first name, last name, email, D.O.B). This is inputted to the table using flask and request.form.

I'm looking for a secure way for the user to create a password, which the database then stores a salt and hash value which can then be de-crypted for login.

To my understanding I should create a password vault table in the same database that would then show the users's: user id, email, salt, hash. The inputted password should be salted (that value stored), then hashed (that value stored).

Tried experimenting with Bcrypt, MD5, SHA256() just for basic hashing first however none seem to like the request.form method.

Comment: Don't implement it yourself, [use passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or something similar. It'll ensure that you avoid most common pitfalls. And generally - the functions or libraries don't integrate with `request.form` - you extract the value from `request.form` and send it into the library/function/etc. for validation.

Comment: You should not be able to decrypt a password, but check the plaintext with the validators provided by the libraries. This page explains all the steps and ideas behind it: https://explore-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users.html

Comment: from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt                                                                                                                            
password = request.form ['password']                                                                
password = sha256_crypt.hash(password)